# when installing /boot inside a lvm group, where do I install the boot loader?

Tags: 12.04, server, grub2, hard-drive, lvm

I am setting a personal file/cloud server based on ubuntu server 12.04 and owncloud but there are certain things about the partitioning that I can't get my head around...

Let's say for example I want to install ubuntu server 12.04 on my machine that has 500GB HDD. I would add 3TB HDDs as time goes on until ether the case or the motherboard doesn't allow me to add more HDDs and in that circumstance I would need to replace the 500GB HDD in which I originally installed the system. By using lvm I could move all the partitions to the other disks while I replace the 500GB HDD but I'm worried about the system not booting: if I install the boot loader on the disk itself, it will be lost when replacing the HDD and if I install the boot loader inside /boot (in the VG) I fear it would not boot or may still have problems when moving files and partitions around with lvm (which is something I need to do when replacing the HDD). I'm also worried about the name of the device conflicting on what I'm trying to do.

Is there a good way to work around this? maybe install everything inside the VG and when I replace the HDD then manually install the boot loader or any other way, I just want to be prepared for the time when I replace the HDD without compromising my data.

note: I'll be using GRUB2 and LVM2.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I think it's useful to distinguish between the initial boot loader (the BIOS), the boot sector on your hard disk (the MBR in the first few bytes of the hard disk) and the second-stage boot loader (GRUB2, on `/boot`).